# Dynamically generating forms in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I have a FormSet to generate Member objects.

```
class MemberBuilder(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
    role = forms.CharField(max_length=128)
```

the FormSet

```
MemberFormSet = formset_factory(MemberBuilder, max_num=30)
```

I would like to display the fields in this form inline like this. [image]

So that when I click Add Member another set of fields is generated underneath like this.

[image]

I can generate additional fields with some jquery in the html.

Is there a pythonic/ Django way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would do this in python/django but in rails you would make it post to the  create action but respond with javascript, then in the script response that gets executed you would update the page with jquery (After ensuring that the form's `remote: true` in the form helper is set of course).

1. I would add listeners with jquery that pick up when the submit button is clicked.
2. Post the data in the form to the create action.
3. Update the html to show that it posted, maybe change the form into plain html with the form values as the html values (you don't need to do this step if you don't want to).
4. Wait for the server to respond with a script (that get's executed)
5. In the script from the server I would find the  **Last**  form (with jquery).
6. Append after it with more html containing another form which is rendered from a partial.

That said, some simple google foo brings up this:

- http://www.micahcarrick.com/ajax-form-submission-django.html
- http://garmoncheg.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/ajax-form-in-django-with-jqueryform.html
- http://schinckel.net/2013/06/13/django-ajax-forms/
- http://twigstechtips.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/django-dynamic-forms-with-dynamic.html
- http://bradmontgomery.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/simple-django-example-with-ajax.html
- https://gist.github.com/goldhand/5791365

I think this one might be the most helpful as it's similar to what you are doing:
http://stellarchariot.com/blog/2011/02/dynamically-add-form-to-formset-using-javascript-and-django/

Take a look at any of them, they all should help.

I have no doubt that someone could probably code a more indepth technical post but it will probably work similar to how I've suggested it.

EDIT: An even better way would be to have the response script call a client side function to do it, that way the response payload is even smaller and thus you have a faster response. Plus having the response script trigger the function means you can be sure that the server side stuff has been executed properly as well.